# Azure Databricks Git Credentials for Service Principals

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks

I would like to create a Databricks job using a [Git reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/how-to/use-repos) to an Azure Devops repo, the reference would ideally use the git credentials of a service principal. [Adding the service principal to the Databricks workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-sp#add-service-principal) is straightforward, as is [adding the service principal to the Azure Devops repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#2-add-and-manage-service-principals-in-an-azure-devops-organization). Configuring the git credentials that the service principal should use is less straightforward. According to the [git credentials API](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/_extras/api-refs/gitcredentials-2.0-azure.yaml#operation/create-git-credential) documentation, the `git_provider` parameter can be;

- `azureDevOpsServices` : requires a username/pat token but doesn't seem to work because of a [limitation on the SP/ADO integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#use-the-azure-ad-token-to-authenticate-to-azure-devops-resources) :

> Service principals can't create tokens, like personal access tokens (PATs) or SSH Keys. They can generate their own Azure AD tokens and these tokens can be used to call Azure DevOps REST APIs.

- `azureDevOpsServicesAAD` : produces the following error from Databricks when the job is run;

> Run result unavailable: run failed with error message  Failed to
> checkout Git repository: PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid Git provider
> credentials. Go to User Settings > Git Integration to ensure that:
>
> 1. You have entered a username with your Git provider credentials.
> 2. You have selected the correct Git provider with your credentials.
> 3. Your personal access token or app password has the correct repo access.
> 4. Your personal access token has not expired.
> 5. If you have SSO enabled with your Git provider, be sure to authorize your token.

Are service principal git credentials supported by Azure Databricks or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't gotten it working either, but I'm still trying.. some interesting caveats here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue over here

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the below steps, it is working for me.

1. Get access token for the service principal with Databricks Scope - 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default  - this token will be used for all api calls for authorization.
2. Get access token for the service principal with Devops scope - 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default - this token will be used only for creating a git credentials entry
3. ADB Rest API - POST - Create a credential entry. Use first token for authorization and second token for personal_access_token in body
   https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/create
4. Create a repo - https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/repos/create
   You should have the repo created for the service principal in Databricks with default branch code downloaded.
5. To update a repo to different branch- Update a repo api call- https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/repos/update

Comment: how to obtain access token in step 2? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token This works but token has an short expiration date

Comment: Yes, access tokens for service principals have 3599 expiration limits. After that time limit, We have to update the credentials with new token. It is better to update the credentials before accessing the repo every time. https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/update
If it is working, please vote.

Answer (score -1):

At the time of writing it seems there are multiple options to actually solve what you are doing:

Assuming you want to use a git provider in the job definition - yes, it seems it is possible to set a token for the service principal in Azure Databricks.

1. You need to go to workspace settings -> personal access tokens -> Permission settings -> add permission to the spervice principal to use tokens.
2. Then with the managing account you can create a token on behalf of the service principal via token API

More here: https://docs.databricks.com/en/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals.html#manage-tokens-for-a-service-principal and here https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/service-principals.html

However this is only half of the issue. To actually pull code you'd need a token for git and this is all ADO/Git provider side.

Maybe what you actually want an answer is **"How to best use git based notebooks?"**

And for that the answer seems to be this:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/repos/ci-cd-techniques-with-repos.html

1. Set up a repo (with whichever user or account as long as Admins can manage it)
2. Use git provider to automatically trigger repo refresh via Databricks API.
3. Set up the job to use a repo based notebook

This again does not seem the most optimal route, but it does remove the hassle to get a working git access token for a service principal. It does move the "service principal" problem to the git provider side as you need a non-personalized setup for this too.

Answer (score -2):

To configure the git credentials in Databricks you can follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-sp#add-creds-to-ws).
You need to first set the AD token in your .databrickscfg file and then run the command:

```
databricks git-credentials create <git-provider-short-name> --git-username <git-provider-user-name> --personal-access-token <git-provider-access-token> -p <profile-name>
```

in this case the *git-provider-access-token* is your git token and not the AD one.

*git-provider-short-name* is one of the following:

- For GitHub, use GitHub.
- For Azure Pipelines, use AzureDevOpsServices.
- For GitLab CI/CD, use GitLab.

Comment: it's a different problem formulated in the question: `Service principals can't create tokens, like personal access tokens (PATs) or SSH Keys.`